# java 13 eclipse: java.lang.module.FindException: Module AbaloneGame not found

Tags: java

When I try and run a class I run into the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module AbaloneGame not found

[Image of the eclipse file explorer for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qiz9.png)

my module-info.java is as follows:

```
module AbaloneGame {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    opens mainGame;
    opens Testing;
}
```

I'm currently at a loss for what causes this error any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module path seems to be set wrong.

Try to change the module name in the module-info.java file to the correct path.

Another way may to eliminate this is to go to the PROJECT folder → src → Default package. Keep only one class (in which you had written code) and delete others.